# Python stopped working on opening Jupiter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter

System Details
Windows 7 32 Bit

After installing anaconda when i try to open any ipynb file in Jupyter notebook it opens a dialog box saying:

> Python has stopped working

Following are the error details:

> Problem signature:   Problem Event Name:  APPCRASH   Application
>   Name: python.exe   Application Version:   3.7.3150.1013   Application
>   Timestamp:    5c9ceaae   Fault Module Name:   KERNELBASE.dll   Fault Module
>   Version:  6.1.7600.16385   Fault Module Timestamp:    4a5bdaae   Exception
>   Code: 40000015   Exception Offset:    00009617   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48   Locale ID:  1033   Additional
>   Information 1:    0a9e   Additional Information
>   2:    0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789   Additional Information 3:    0a9e
>   Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Comment: Can you run Python outside of the Jupyter environment? Are you sure you installed the 32-bit version of Python?

Comment: I can run python code from cmd console

Comment: I didn't install python seperatly I just installed 32 bit version  anaconda for Windows I m sure anconda  that I installed was 32 bit

Comment: Great, that helps to narrow down a little bit. Can you give details on how you are running your Jupyter notebook server? Just trying to think of other things which may help diagnose the problem (I don't have an answer unfortunately, but others may).

Comment: I open anaconda and click on Jupiter notebook . Once I try to create a new file there it prompts me with the same msg described above

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. That took several days for me to find out my issue. I installed different versions of Anaconda and read many documents and performed many commands to upgrade but none of them resolved my problem. I think the Operating System (OS) version is not compatible with Anaconda's embedded python version (or Anaconda version). You can try different Operating System versions or different Anaconda versions. I found two versions of Anaconda which worked correctly (OS: Windows 7, 64 bit SP1). You can download them from the following link:

https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/

1. Anaconda3-5.3.1-Windows-x86_64.exe (Python version: 3.7.0)
2. Anaconda2-5.3.1-Windows-x86_64.exe (Python version: 2.7)

Because you use OS: WIN 7, 32 bit, you can download the 32-bit version of the above Anaconda.